# Call a method call after every page-flip UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

Initially I thought this is a pretty simple thing but looks like it's not. I need to make a simple GET request to my server whenever a page flip happens in my UIPageViewController. I have tried putting the method to make the server call in methods like :

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

But none of these methods get called consistently after every page flip as UIPageViewController tries to maintain a cache of viewcontrollers I guess. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 4):

You should implement `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` method

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
{
    if (finished) {
       // in case you are sure that you shows only YourViewController 
       YourViewController *vc = (YourViewController *)pageViewController.viewControllers.lastObject;
       // decide what is the index of the controller based on your own logic and do what you want with it 
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, and of course, make sure to set the delegate as the object who implements this method.

Comment: Is there anyway I can use the index of page being flipped or that's been flipped in the above method?

Comment: Added description how to receive index of UIViewController that was shown